# Setting ImageView as bitmap in layoutinflator container

Tags: android, bitmap, popup, imageview

I am trying to open my camera via an intent, and store the resulting image as a bitmap. Then, upon clicking a marker in Google Maps, I want to pass this bitmap into another layout that will be used to populate a popup window in the main activities layout.

However, I am getting the error: 
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference"

Here are portions of my code:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // if the action was to capture a picture, then store all relevant data in the database
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Received"/*data.getData().toString()*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.imagecontainer, null);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 800, 1220, true);
    popUpWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popUpWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popUpWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    return false;
}
```

imagecontainer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/imageContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean (missed container?):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put "container" in front.